# Proper placing of external javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the best place to put <script> tags in HTML markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)

I have been studying javascript for quite sometime now, and one of my  main concerns are am I learning the proper practice, I've asked different people regarding this but They seem to give me pretty vague answers, I know External stylesheet should be placed inside the head tag but when it comes to Javascript? should I put my external javascript in the head tag? or in the bottom of body tag(before the ending tag)?

Answer (score 0):

The simple reason why you should put all `<script>` nodes at the very bottom of your `<body>` tag is, that `<script>` nodes will block the DOM render process and the browsers "UI thread".

In modern browsers you can workaround that issue by indicating attributes like `defer` and `async`, but old'ish browsers don't know about those.